# parsing to external Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have an external `mailer.php` that is messing up.  I know the code works with `php 5.4` or better, but I am unable to even SEE which version of PHP that the server is using. (got to love using college servers)

I get the following error after I submit:

```
Call to undefined function  http_response_code() in **site here**mailer.php on line 37
```

This is my code of lines 34-43 with line 37 having -- in front of it (NOT part of the code):

PHP

```
// Send the email.
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
  // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
  --http_response_code(200);
  echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
} else {
  // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
  http_response_code(500);
  echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
}
```

I do receive the email, then I'm sent to a blank page with the error message.

I was wondering if instead of receiving that code (or the other 4 lines down) I could instead send a message to jQuery, and if so, how I would go about doing it?

**Note**  jQuery is on HTML page.

Comment: To check the PHP version and other informations, create a .php page and write in it: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. When you'll open it in the browser, you'll get the infos you need

Comment: [This comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php#107261) on the `http_response_code()` doc page describes a way to create your own version of the function if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the email.

```
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {

        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }
```

why would you trigger a http response code if it error's it will set the error for you.. 
if it doesn't it will also return it for you

Comment: Not my script..... Like I said before, I am less then a noob when it comes to PHP.

How would I parse a message to my jquery?  Wouldn't the echo be posted to the screen? Or is that a behind the scenes chatter?

Comment: After I did some research on your answer, I was able to get it to work.  Thanks.  BTW, My comment about me being less then a noob at PHP was edited out.... :-\

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output to be the same, you can use [`header()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) instead by replacing:

```
http_response_code(500);
echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
```

with:

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . " 500 Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.", true, 500);
```

The same applies to the other calls to the same undefined function, for example:

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . " 200 Thank You! Your message has been sent.", true, 200);
```